# Copy and Paste a Range of Cells to another sheet if a cell outside the range =Resolved then delete the row

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have multiple sheets for storing records of payments (things to be Pay and CantPay). I am trying to write a macro that will copy and paste Cells A:M on every row where column T = "Resolved" on the CantPay sheet (where the next empty row is the next row where "a" & row-number = blank) to the "Pay" sheet.

Within the sheet which i want to copy from there is data in columns A:T but N:T are not needed once the problem is resolved. So once i have copy and pasted the data within cells A:M i want to just delete the entire row. I have written some code from what i knew and looking online which isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried recording a macro and writing my own but it seems the macro i have wrote is deleting row 1 which is where all my column headers are stored.

```
Sub MoveToPay()

Dim CantPay As Worksheet: Set CopySheet = Sheets("Can't Pay")
Dim ReadyToPay As Worksheet: Set PasteSheet = Sheets("£ Pay")
Dim lr As Long
Dim S As String


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Columns(20).AutoFilter 1, "Resolved"
With Range("a2", Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    .Copy PasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1)
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
Columns(20).AutoFilter


Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine , where is your header stored and Is it deleted the first time when you run the code ?

Comment: so initially i used a different range and it seemed to copy and paste fine but then i changed the range it started to delete Row 1 where all my headers are.

Initally used this code:
With Range("a2", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3))